# Load compressed data into BigQuery from AWS S3 using bq command

Tags: amazon-s3, google-bigquery

It seems that I can load data into BigQuery from S3 in the following sample:
This time, I would like to load the compressed files in S3. Not a CSV file.
If so, how can I load the data into BigQuery from S3?

sample

```
bq mk \
  --transfer_config  \
  --data_source=amazon_s3 \
  --display_name=load_from_s3 \
  --target_dataset=test_dataset_s3 \
  --params='{
"data_path":"s3://xxx-test01",
"destination_table_name_template":"test_table",
"access_key_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"secret_access_key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"file_format":"CSV",
"max_bad_records":"0",
"ignore_unknown_values":"true",
"field_delimiter":",",
"skip_leading_rows":"0",
"allow_quoted_newlines":"true"
}'
```

Comment: What is the compression type? For CSVs `gzip` is the only supported file compression type.

Comment: The file is *.gz. It is gzip compression.

Comment: Hello. If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

The same `bq` CLI command can be used without much changes. Assuming you have compressed `CSV` files, I tested the transfer with a sample compressed file of my own and the transfer was successful. Below is the `bq` command I tested.

```sh
bq mk \
  --transfer_config  \
  --data_source=amazon_s3 \
  --display_name=load_from_s3 \
  --target_dataset=test_dataset \
  --params='{
"data_path":"s3://awsbucket-name/sample.csv.gz",
"destination_table_name_template":"table-name",
"access_key_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"secret_access_key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"file_format":"CSV",
"max_bad_records":"0",
"ignore_unknown_values":"true",
"field_delimiter":",",
"skip_leading_rows":"1",
"allow_quoted_newlines":"true"
}'
```

**Logs of the file transfer:**
[image]

However, it is also to be noted that for formats such as `CSV` and `JSON`, BigQuery can load uncompressed files significantly faster than compressed files because uncompressed files can be read in parallel. For more information refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data).